# Shell - PTS/0 Suddenly Changed to PTS/1 Why did it happen and how to change it back?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Whenever I enter the who command in the SSH I see the PTS/1 after my username. Two days ago it was still PTS/0. Is this called the TTY?

How do I make it PTS/0 again? Also the path now is /dev/pts/1 and the shell is still /bin/bash.

Update: Whenever I kill a particular process the pts/0 returns. But when I start the process again it would become pts/1 again. Can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If there's anyone who could answer my question on why a process could change the pts/...I'll be glad.Does this mean that process has opened up its own terminal? That's why when I connect I always go to pts/1. Forgive me if I'm really just confused and lost. Maybe I'm just paranoid that a process could intercept my commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo-terminal slave, e.g.,`/dev/pts/1` is allocated each time you open a terminal.  It can be different if there is more than one terminal that has been opened.

Further reading:

- [Control pseudo-terminal (/dev/pts/*) assignments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/control-pseudo-terminal-dev-pts-assignments)
- [What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them)

Comment: I use SSH and PUTTY. I think I only have one terminal open everytime I connect on my server. And when I open a new instance of the shell, it always becomes pts/2.

Comment: Now I see something. If I kill a particular process, my username becomes pts/0 again. Please explain this and can I prevent this from happening? I discovered this when I restarted the server thinking that it would go away. But when I started that process the pts/0 became pts/1 again. Thanks for the links they were very helpful.

Comment: What is the "particular process" which you killed?

Comment: It's the TeamTalk server. I'd start it by typing ./tt5srv -d. I'd kill it by typing kill pid or killall tt5srv.

Comment: Sounds like TeamTalk is opening a pseudo-terminal and whoever gets there first gets `/dev/pts/0`.  I would not rely on a particular path, but just use the output of `tty`.